# Bootstrap element is floating, but I want it to stick to another element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is how it should be:
[image: Picture 1]

When Breakfast element is small enough, the profile element will try to get in there. Below is an example of that.

[image: Picture 2]

I want each 'profile' to stick to the 'meals' no matter what.

I'm using bootstrap - 'col-md-4' and 'well'

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5jag5bay/1/ - This is the section where I did this

Comment: Try solving some things first:
<div class="well dash-box style="max-height: 10;">
Should be:
<div class="well dash-box" style="max-height: 10;">
And a <p> should always have a </p> after and a </p> should always have a <p> before

Comment: @Maikel what is your problem? works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/r7pthz8f/

Comment: This is what that fiddle renders as once bootstrap is added and a few tags are fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/9mfv3fva/

Comment: Here's a revision that divides the pairs of people and meals into `col-md-6` wide columns with nested `col-sm-4` and `col-sm-8` instead of `col-md-2` and `col-md-4` only. https://jsfiddle.net/9mfv3fva/5/.  That might fix your issue; but I, like the others, am having a difficult time reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I approve of the second option you provided, https://jsfiddle.net/9mfv3fva/5/.

Comment: You have all of the elements in one `row` div.  You should have each row in its own div with the class `row`

Comment: @sn3ll Is right.  Problem: https://jsfiddle.net/q99uvh2b/ Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/9mfv3fva/7/.  You should write it out as a solution, sn3ll.

Comment: Thank you. You truly are a gifted genius. My goodness you are all amazing. Thanks ;c